# Battery charger DIY

Tags: transformer, ac, battery-charging, bridge-rectifier

Can I use 220-12 V, 1.5 A stepdown transformer along with 12 V 2 A ([KBP200](http://www.eicsemi.com/DataSheet/KBP200_10.pdf)) bridge rectifier to build a charger for 12 V, 7.5 Ah battery or should I use transformer with higher output, maybe 15 V?

Comment: You need about 14.4 V DC to fully charge a 12 V lead-acid battery. Please calculate your peak voltage minus your voltage drop across the rectifier and report back.

Comment: Maybe. 12 x 1.414 ~= 16.8V. - bridge about 1.5V =~~ 15.3V. That gives about 1v headroom for "droop" and not peak rectification . This assumes NO regulator with attendanty drop. ie for a brutal unregulated charger it would charge at some rate. With any added regulation you'd want more AC voltage.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you add a couple of diodes in series on the middle pin of the voltage regulator (assuming the OP was including a regulator) to increase the voltage to what is required?

Comment: He's asking if Vin_AC is adequate. The diodes for a regulator only work if VinAC is above what he has specified as headroom is v low